# How to add a print dialog to an application

Tags: application-development, python, printing, gtk

I'd like to add a print dialog to my Python + GTK app, and I believe there are at least two methods:

1. [The upstream GTK print dialog](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk/stable/GtkPrintUnixDialog.html)
2. The CUPS print dialog

I'm wondering which would be the recommended one to use for application development. I believe 2. is what Ubuntu uses, so I assume it will work well with indicators and with detecting system printers. However, I haven't been able to find any documentation at all for it.

Any recommendation on the best way to add a print dialog to my app?

Comment: what do you mean by "ubuntu uses the CUPS dialog"? What part of Ubuntu? I think most (all) applications inherited from Gnome use the upstream GTK dialog. I would recommend you to do the same.

Comment: I simply said "I believe", as I'm not familiar with printing at all, so any advice, corrections or code snippets are welcome. I looked at https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-q-common-print-dialog and I got the impression that there isn't a standard print dialog all apps use yet.

Comment: Programming questions should be asked on stackoverflow.

Comment: @psusi: Programming in Ubuntu is a topic of AskUbuntu, please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that a reasonable way to add printing to your app with Gtk would be the [Gtk.PrintOperation](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.0/gtk3-High-level-Printing-API.html). This is supposed to be the high-level, portable version of a print dialog.

In Python, a basic example could look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

class MyWindow(Gtk.Window):

    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Hello World Printing")
        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Print A Rectangle")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.on_button_clicked)
        self.add(self.button)

    def on_button_clicked(self, widget):
        pd = Gtk.PrintOperation()
        pd.set_n_pages(1)
        pd.connect("draw_page", self.draw_page)
        result = pd.run(
            Gtk.PrintOperationAction.PRINT_DIALOG, None)
        print result  # handle errors etc.

    def draw_page(self, operation=None, context=None, page_nr=None):
        ctx = context.get_cairo_context()
        w = context.get_width()
        h = context.get_height()
        ctx.set_source_rgb(0.5, 0.5, 1)
        ctx.rectangle(w*0.1, h*0.1, w*0.8, h*0.8)
        ctx.stroke()
        return


win = MyWindow()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Comment: This is the correct way. It will try to run the native printdialog for the user's system.